# How can I lock table in mysql using C API?

Tags: mysql, c, locking

How can I lock read/write to MySQL tables or rows using C API so that I can select and then insert without other programs reading/writing to the database?

Is it possible to use something like:

```
mysql_query(conn, "LOCK TABLE myTable");
```